# Getting Output as "-nan" in conversion tool at specific value

Tags: c

I made a simple tool to convert the RGB colour format into the CMYK format. I checked the values with an online converted for the values entered and I am getting right output except when I enter the RGB = (0,0,0) , I get the output in the CMY values as "-nan" whereas in Black I get the correct value i.e. 1. Here is the source Code to the program written -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

float max(float,float,float);

int main()
{
    float r,g,b;
    float white,cyan,magenta,yellow,black;
    printf("\nPlease Enter The Values Of Red, Green And Blue");
    scanf("%f%f%f",&r,&g,&b);
    if(r>=0 && r<=255 && g>=0 && g<=255 && b>=0 && b<=255)
    {
    white=max(r/255,g/255,b/255);
    cyan=(white-r/255)/white;
    magenta=(white-g/255)/white;
    yellow=(white-b/255)/white;
    black=1.0-white;

        printf("The Converted Values In CMYK format are Cyan = %f Magenta = %f Yellow = %f Black = %f",cyan,magenta,yellow,black);
}
    else
    printf("\nThe Values Entered Of RGB Colours Are Wrong. Please Recheck Them");

    return 0;
}

float max(float a,float b,float c)
{
    float z;
    if(a==b && b==c)
        z=a;
    else
    z=(a>b)?(a>c?a:c):(b>c?b:c);
    return z;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get a `nan` if you divide a zero by zero in this case if `white` is 0. You can't divide zero by zero because the result is not a number(that's what `nan` stands for). To avoid that add special handling for the case when `white` is 0.

Comment: So in order to resolve this situation, I need to add another If Condition? or is there any other way to display the Zero?

Comment: You add an if. And also keep in mind strict comparison of floats is not the best thing to do. Better handle values close enough to zero for instance: `if (white > -1e-9 && white < 1e-9)`.

Comment: Any specific reason for comparing like this? Asking this because I am new to C.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: using a tolerance to compare floating-point values is not necessary when comparing for the purpose of dividing by zero. Please do not spread this myth about comparing floating-point numbers.

Comment: (a) division by zero doesn't typically produce NaN; 0/0 does. (b) there's no reason to use an approximate comparison here, as NaN will only result if `white` is *exactly* zero.

Comment: Of course it is not necessary but if you have special handling for the zero case it will also apply for numbers close enough to zero right. The usual case is that 0 value is handled in a simpler manner. I never said it is necessary only said `strict comparison of floats is not the best thing to do`

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: In the most commonly used floating-point system (IEEE 754), dividing by zero generally does not produce NaN. Dividing a non-zero number by zero produces an infinity. Dividing zero by zero produces NaN.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: in this particular instance, "strict comparison of floats" is **precisely** "the best thing to do".

Comment: @StephenCanon I do not agree with that and may take this discussion to chat if you want. Small floating numbers calculation is never a good idea and if you can you better avoid it.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: Please do not spread the myth that strict comparison of floats is not the best thing to do. It is situation-dependent and is often advised incorrectly. Dividing by a non-zero number will **not** produce a NaN, even if it is very close to zero. Therefore there is no reason to use a tolerance when comparing for this purpose.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I already read your previous comment no need to repeat yourself. I am not spreading any myth just pointing what is the best practise. As pointed above I am ready to take that discussion to chat if you want.

Comment: There's nothing to discuss.  There is no combination of `r`,`g`,`b` inputs that will produce incorrect behavior if a strict comparison is used.  If an approximate comparison is used instead, the algorithm will produce incorrect output for any set of `r`, `g`, and `b` that fall below the threshold.

Comment: A floating point division does not have infinite accuracy so there will be an ever even without a threshold. There are cases when dividing by a small value may cause your program to execute about 10 times slower see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) and [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/1980).

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: Per the IEEE-754 specification, floating-point division is performed as if with infinite accuracy and is then rounded to the target format. Given the specification, dividing a non-zero number by a non-zero number will **never** produce a NaN, regardless of how close to zero the divisor is. The performance issues with using subnormal numbers are not an issue in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You are dividing by zero. What result did you expect?

Your code is pretty strange to begin with, why scan floats if yuo expect them to be in the 8-bit range of 0..255?

You need to protect against the division by checking if the value is 0 before doing the divide. When it is 0, you need to substitute whatever value makes the most sense, probably zero for all of the CMY components. The black (K) will become 1 if `white` is 0, which is what you want.

Comment: @Chinna It's not a comment, it's an answer to the question of why NaN is occuring. I added more text to make it clearer and to suggest how to fix it.

Comment: @unwind Thanks for elaborating in this deep. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `white` is 0, and you are trying to divide by `Zero/Zero`. `nan` stands for `Not A Number`. You will get this when you try to divide by zero.

```
white=max(r/255,g/255,b/255);//will return 0 if you enter r = 0.0,g = 0.0,b = 0.0
```

So, `white` will be having `0.0`;

```
cyan=(white-r/255)/white; // here you are doing 0.0/0.0 (white = 0.0, r = 0.0)
```

Comment: Ya, correction, I didnt notice that I did put in that way!!! will update that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case of ‘‘divide-by-zero’’ floating point exception. You should consider this case in your program to avoid it.